# Where can i find all right-to-left characters in UTF-8?

Tags: html, unicode, utf-8, character

I know that Hebrew and Arabic characters are going from right to left but I want to see all of them.

Comment: what do you mean  `I want to see all of them`?

Comment: Are there any more right to left characters besides Arabic and Hebrew?

Comment: Can single characters go to left or right?

Comment: Explain your question with an example !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at the [bidirectional character type](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Bidirectional_Character_Types) (Unicode character property Bidi_Class). You're looking for characters of type `R` (Right-to-Left) or `AL` (Right-to-Left Arabic). The file [`DerivedBidiClass.txt`](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/extracted/DerivedBidiClass.txt) in the Unicode database contains a list of all code points with these classes.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting i18nguy:

> Languages don't have a direction. Scripts have a writing direction,
>   and so languages written in a particular script, will be written with
>   the direction of that script.

Here are some scripts using RTL: Arabic, Hebrew, N'ko, Syriac, Thaana/Thâna, Tifinar, Urdu.

You can just look for unicode range of a given script. Like for example Tifinar: U+2D30 – U+2D7F.

Not sure what you want to achieve by looking at all those characters but I think that is the only way of actually finding them.

You can refer to the original page here:
http://www.i18nguy.com/temp/rtl.html