# How to concatenate Arabic string first and English second in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, arabic

I am trying to concatenate Arabic string first and English second. But its printing English first and Arabic next.

**Example**

```
select  'يوم' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @StartDate, 103)
```

it's printing in reverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any knowloge about arabic but I think the following queries will help to solve your issue;

```
    select nchar(8237)  + (N'يوم') +  nchar(8236) +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDAte(), 103) AS ConvertType
    UNION ALL
    select nchar(8237)  + reverse(N'يوم') +  nchar(8236) +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDAte(), 103)


+-----------------+
|   ConvertType   |
+-----------------+
| ‭يوم‬10/11/2019 |
| ‭موي‬10/11/2019 |
+-----------------+
```

Also you can refer the [How to fix reversed arabic characters mixed with english in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48147690/reverse-characters-in-string-with-mixed-left-to-right-and-right-to-left-language)